# How can i delete a new language or replace with a change Version in Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1

Tags: spring-roo

I have now an new Language in Roo but i wan't to change the properties File and build language new.
When i install language with

```
addon install url --url file:///E://org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.i18n-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

the old Version not replaces.

How can i delete the old Version or replace with the newer one?

I have testet with addon remove but --bundleSymbolicName is required. My language addon not shown in List.

When i type addon list i see my addon.

I can delete the new folder created in spring roo folder cache and then i can add the language new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.i18n` that you're using to your i18n addon is not recommendable. The reason is that already exists an official Spring Roo addon with that name and maybe some conflict could appear.

I recommend you to use some other name to your i18n addon. In my case, I could use something like `org.jcagarcia.i18n.de`.

After install it, this addon should appear in the `addon remove --bundleSymbolicName` autocompletion list with the name `org.jcagarcia.i18n.de`.

If not, the other option you could try is to close the spring roo shell and remove the `/cache` folder from your `spring-roo-2.0.0.RC1` distribution folder. Re-open the Spring Roo shell and all the installed addons should be removed.

Hope it helps,

Regards,

Comment: Thanks this was the Problem ;)

Comment: Glad to head that my answer helps you! :)